# How do I make buckwheat pancakes without non-stick cookware?

Tags: substitutions, cookware

Recently I tried to make buckwheat pancakes, but failed miserably. I tried heating the stainless steel pan (about 12" in diameter) for a few seconds on medium heat, then I applied some safflower oil (about two teaspoons). When I poured the mixture on the heated pan, it immediately stuck...So I couldn't even get past the "flip the pancake" part of the instructions.

Is it possible to make pancakes still? If so, how?

Comment: You have enough rep now I think to join us chat.  That is a good place to ask some questions, since we can talk to you and find out more.   Here, I wonder if you had your pan too hot or not hot enough, or if you waited long enough, but it is hard to say.   Chat link is at the top of the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"For a few seconds", if literal, is the problem.  You want to make sure that the pan is well heated before adding your batter.

My mom's test was to sprinkle some water on the pan, and see if the droplets danced around.  [Leidenfrost effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect).

As you're using quite a bit of oil, you can also look for the shimmering that will happen just before the oil starts to smoke as an indication of a well-heated pan.

Comment: It's also worth holding your hand a short distance above the pan sometimes, just to get a sense for how fast your stove heats your pan. It's not a test for proper temperature (at least not until you develop some instincts) but it'll make the difference between a few seconds and a few minutes really obvious.

Comment: For estimating temperatures, see : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12263/67

Answer (score 0):

Waiting until the pan is hot enough is definitely important. Use butter, not oil, then wipe off with a towel, leaving a thin layer. also, wait until the pancake has cooked significantly on one side before flipping. I think it has to do with the proteins being cooked well enough that it releases itself from the pan. The pan does not need to be re-oiled after that. In addition, from my experience, the quality of the stainless pan makes a difference. My cheap low end Calphalon stuck whereas my expensive All-Clad didn't. A well seasoned cast iron pan is also another option. Cooked as well as my Teflon coated pans.