# Frying panko crusted pork chops

Tags: frying

I've been trying to fry panko coated pork chops. Followed standard recipe which includes seasoning, dipping it in egg wash and milk, coating it with panko breadcrumbs, the usual drill. However, when I go and fry it the crust starts to char and burn midway through the cooking process, while the actual meat is nowhere near cooked.

Does that have something to do with oil temperature? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

That definitely sounds like your pan is too hot. That's a bit unusual as most often people have difficulty with the opposite problem. Here's a great [video](http://rouxbe.com/cooking-school/lessons/173-the-water-test-heating-the-pan) on testing pan temperature with water. If your pan is non-stick, look here: [How can you judge when a non-stick pan is the correct temperature for pan frying?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/how-can-you-judge-when-a-non-stick-pan-is-the-correct-temperature-for-pan-frying?rq=1). At any rate, try lowering your temperature.